# C# writeline cap

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that writes to a file that requires specific positions:

it looks something like:

```
writer.WriteLine("{0,-3}{1,-5}{2,-30}", data1, data2, data3);
```

The positions that it starts is correct however, if data1 exceeds 3 character, it pushes the format by the exceeded amount,

Is there a way to make data1 cap at 3 characters and ignore any excess characters using the writeline format?

Comment: show desired result.

Comment: Could you show values of `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, expected output and actual output?

Comment: you could try `Substring()` such as `data1.Substring(0,3)`

Comment: Should the data be *trimmed* e.g. `abcdef` -> `abc`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yup, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should "safely substring" (`Substring` throws an exception if you choose a length greater than the string length) your strings to the desidered lenght.

```
public static string SafeSubstring(this string text, int start, int length)
{
    return text.Length <= start ? string.Empty
        : text.Length - start <= length ? text.Substring(start)
        : text.Substring(start, length);
}
```

Then, for example:

```
writer.WriteLine("{0,-3}{1,-5}{2,-30}", 
    data1.SafeSubstring(0, 3), 
    data2.SafeSubstring(0, 3), 
    data3.SafeSubstring(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Substring`. This code trims the string if it's longer than 3 characters:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-3}{1,-5}{2,-30}",
                  data1.Substring(0,data1.Length > 3 ? 3 : data1.Length), 
                  data2, data3);
```

Comment: it will fail if `data1` has less than `3` characters

Comment: `data1.Substring(0,data1.Length)` does nothing

Comment: beware, if `data1` is shorter than 3 characters, `Substring` will throw an exception

Comment: @Nino i have fixed that now

Comment: @DmitryBychenko fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this with *formatting alone*, but you can implement a (extension) method:

```
   public static string ToLength(this object value, int length) {
     if (length == 0)
       return "";
     else if (null == value)
       return new string(' ', Math.Abs(length));

     string v = value.ToString();

     if (v.Length >= Math.Abs(length))
       return v.Substring(0, Math.Abs(length));
     else if (length < 0)
       return v.PadRight(-length);  
     else
       return v.PadLeft(length);   
   }
```

Then use it

```
   writer.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", 
     data1.ToLength(-3), 
     data2.ToLength(-5), 
     data3.ToLength(-30));
```

I've implemented extension method for `object`, not `string` since you may want to put *any* object to stream.

Comment: You forgot `string` in the method signature.

Comment: @adjan: Thank you! I've edited the answer and corrected the typo